# Rest API in Spring Boot application not able to access on local network

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm developing a REST api using Spring Boot with tomcat. The API is accessible on the same system using postman but not able access on other system which is connect with same wifi.   [image: hot]

**application.properties**

```
#Mongo db setting ...
spring.data.mongodb.database=testdb
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017

#setting for server port
server.port=8080
server.address=192.168.0.117



spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Comment: What url you are using? What error are you getting on the other system?

Comment: http://192.168.0.117:8080/api/post

Comment: Could you please post your Connector defined in server.xml? Maybe your binding to localhost only.

Comment: @Simon I'm not using any server.xml file in my project. I'm added application.properties file in my queastion

Comment: @VijayKumar, can you quickly verify that the other system can successfully ping 192.168.0.117 (ie. your wifi router isn't blocking the connection).

Comment: @Simon, Yes, other system is pinging successfully

Comment: server.address=0.0.0.0.try this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Enable Firewall port for tomcat on your windows machine.

Goto Windows Firewall->Advanced Settings->Inbound Rules.

In the Right side click on New Rule->Then select Port from the dialog box and Next->Then type port "8080" (As by default Tomcat run on this port) and Next->Then select "Allow the connection"->Next->Give a Name ->Finish.

Comment: I believe that's the firewall problem

Comment: but i'm allowing the 8080 in Inbound rule

Comment: Other system is pinging successfully -> router isn't blocked the connection -> Firewall blocked your request.

Comment: If you are using Windows 10, allow Tomcat to communicate through the firewall: 
1. Enable Private and Public for "Commons Daemon Service Runner"
2. Add a firewall exception for javaw. Find Java(TM) Platform SE binary with a path to javaw (add as above if not present) -> Enable Private and Public for it.

Comment: How to do this**1. Enable Private and Public for "Commons Daemon Service Runner**

Comment: This step: Control Panel -> System and Security -> Windows Firewall -> "Allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall" -> "Change settings" -> Enable Private and Public for "Commons Daemon Service Runner"

Comment: if not present: "Allow another app..." -> Chose tomcat#.exe in Tomcat bin directory. Make sure your windows version is PRO or Enterprise (not Home)

Comment: Thanks Its Working :)

Comment: what about linux users please ? :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe opening the port will help

If you use Windows you can run this bat file to open the port:

```
@echo off
set port=8080
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port%port%" protocol="TCP" localport=%port% action=allow dir=IN
echo %port% port opened
pause
```

To close the port:

```
@echo off
set port=8080
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="Port%port%"
echo %port% port closed
pause
```

P.S. Didn't noticed that Jun already answered about firewall rule.